# How does current flow when pairing a voltage generator with a current source?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, current-source

in the following circuit :
http://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcZYA4BsB2ATNzZsEBOVA9EAZnKQUhAQFMBaMMAKAHcQAWb1EbJH4JeAoVE71RFQTz6VZkSenGD+K-tm50lASxAbKkbgdXao4ZeIrHT-GTsm9NCcs4WOKmOobVSTfhCOAG5yLm7yfjo8dEjRMAhsXrHSsoYO4BZKQA

should the current flow from the positive terminal of the voltage generator to the negative one ? , why is it the opposite . also does the real (non ideal) current generator exist in real life ?

Comment: how does it flow without the current source?

Comment: from positive terminal to negative one like this http://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcZYA4BsB2ATNzZsEBOVA9EBVCiyCgUwFowwAoAdxG0iuwBZaAzJF6d+UdiCEiBCbJ26TZ4jgPQ8xqnjmWS1k1bqoy5kCVx6oeC4+IGZBevoOGjaEWqYBu8i1fUeoEDEkAJgEFjtnaSVNRTl3cQAnQ05tWIEDN3gWIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current passed by a voltage source is determined exclusively by the circuit external to the voltage source.

The voltage across a current source is determined exclusively by the circuit external to the current source.

So the direction of current (and its magnitude) in a circuit consisting of a voltage source in parallel with a current source is completely determined by the current source.

The polarity of the voltage (and its magnitude) across the circuit is completely determined by the voltage source.

Comment: also does the real (non ideal) current generator exist in real life ?

Comment: Well, kind-of. There’s several circuits that can approximate a current source within limits. Ask another question. You should get several answers .